# javascript not updating a variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have  a asp.net application which i am trying to create a progress bar which run with the system, I am using Java Script to do the update progress and would like an idea on how i would be update `var update = 0;` and this `$("#progressbar").progressbar('value', update);` in the code below without using a for loop, as i all ready have used a for loop and booleans,  the system throws an error of a long running progra.  the rest of the java script code is blow,  I would like to update it up to the value of 60;

**JavaScript which is being called**

```
   $.updateProgressbar = function () {
        //Calling PageMethod for current progress
        PageMethods.OperationProgress(function (result) {

            //Updating progress
            $("#progressbar").progressbar('value', result.progress)
            //If operation is complete
            if (result.progress == 100) {
                //Enable button
                $("#Confirm_btn").attr('disabled', '');
            }
            //If not
            else {
                //Reset timer
                setTimeout($.updateProgressbar, 10);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Progressbar initialization
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
        //Button click event
        $("#Confirm_btn").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            //Disabling button
            $('#error').text("");
            $("#Confirm_btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            var update = 0;


            //Making sure that progress indicate 0
            $("#progressbar").progressbar('value', update);
            //Call PageMethod which triggers long running operation
            PageMethods.Operation(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    //Updating progress
                    $("#progressbar").progressbar('value', result.progress)
                    //Setting the timer
                    setTimeout($.updateProgressbar, 5);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to call a function repeated times, so this function can trigger a ajax function or simple update the progresBar. This isn't block your program.

Comment: In your case, you can declare the variable `update` out of the `ready` block. So you can access its value or set it.

Comment: Show me what u mean please new to javascipt

Comment: You need to declare `var update = 0;` before the line `$.updateProgressbar = function () {`

Answer (score 0):

PageMethods.OperationProgress does not seem to return a proper result object in the callback function. thats why your app is running endless and why your progress-bar isnt updated

Comment: it does, because it a cc# methos